# Could not resolve host in docker

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, dns

I'm trying to do an jenkins on docker, on my machine (Ubuntu).

I have to access to the git repo, in my company.
But in jenkins, I get this error :

> Could not resolve host: gogs.mycompany.com

I think this is an DNS error, so I tried to launch my docker like that (with --dns and --dns-search)

> sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v
> /home/xero/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
> --name=myproject-jenkins2 --dns=127.0.1.1 --dns-search=mycompany.lan jenkins

Here my /etc/resolv.conf :

> nameserver 127.0.1.1
>
> search mycompany.lan

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNS was wrong. (--dns=127.0.1.1)

This DNS server, is an internal DNS, Dnsmasq, it's a DNS forwarder.

So I needed to know the real internal DNS server :

```
nmcli dev show | grep DNS
```

And add the right address (10.0.1.1 in my case) :

> sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v
>   /home/xero/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home --name=myproject-jenkins2
>   --dns=10.0.1.1 jenkins

Comment: bash: --dns=x.y.z.m: invalid option

Comment: @MonaJalal https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services

Comment: @MonaJalal, you should drop the '='. Just do --dns x.y.z.m